# Android TextView with a drag bar

Tags: android, textview

Now I have a textview floating  on another , may be a player
and the text and his rectangle is scable、rotatable by the yellow icon, and movable by drag the text.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a layout containing both your text view and a button (or another view depending on what you want to do with it), and then implement the methods that will discribe the behavior of your new custom view.